# Is there an integrity constraint violation if a search with a different domain is made?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, erd

These are the tables and the relational schema given:

[image: tables and the relational schema]

Would the following action cause a **domain** constraint violation?

**Delete any tuple in Collaborators with ‘requestorNumericSuffix’ = 'QUR'.**

I think it wouldn't, because even though the domain for the request is wrong, it's just not gonna find any matches.

But I'm not so sure, so I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Even if there was a match COLABORATORS are referencing USERS.
The delete shouldn't raise an error. The other way around will cause an error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).